# Orchard Taxonomy Terms get direct children in view

Tags: razor, orchardcms, taxonomy, orchard-modules, orchardcms-1.8

I have a Taxonomy called Categories. In this taxonomy I have multiple levels of terms. Each term is a CategoriesTerm contenttype.

I have defined a custom razor template: `Content-CategoriesTerm.cshtml`, which is used when I click a CategoriesTerm on the frontend.

Now I want to display on that page all direct children (if any), but there is no property like `Term.Children` or something. How can I get the children of a term in the Razor view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `Taxonomy.cshtml` and `Orchard.Mvc.DisplayChildren`. It goes like this:

```
 var tag = Tag(Model, "ul");
    IList<dynamic> items = Model.Items;

    if (items.Any()) {
        items[0].Classes.Add("first");
        items[items.Count - 1].Classes.Add("last");

<div>
    @tag.StartElement
        @* see MenuItem shape template *@
        @DisplayChildren(Model)
    @tag.EndElement
</div>
```

@DisplayChildren could be done in Razor if you like:

```
 public IHtmlString DisplayChildren(dynamic shape) {
        var writer = new HtmlStringWriter();
        foreach (var item in shape) {
            writer.Write(Display(item));
        }
        return writer;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am a bit confused though. Looking at `Taxonomy.cshtml` I see this code indeed, but isn't this to display the children of a **Taxonomy**? I am trying to display the children of a **Term**.

Comment: My Bad, it was TaxonomyItem.cshtml. Nevertheless, that is the way. You could also do it in one View, but always better to use whats there... IMHO.

Comment: Maybe I'm that dumb, but how can I use this? Should I add this code to my `Content-CategoriesTerm.cshtml`?

Comment: Yes, going back to your question. There is no Term.Children but there is a Model.Items that is what you should be using. User the Designer Tools and you can see your Model properties.

Comment: Really thanks for taking your time to answer this (probably easy) question, but I try something simple like `@{
  var children = Model.Items;

if(children == null)
{
<span>nothing</span>
}
else
{
<span>@children.Count</span>
}

}` and it always says `0`, while there are 2 childterms..

Comment: Have you enabled Designer Tools yet? Do that. Learn to use it. It will help you so much in order to understand whats going on. Seriously. Read this: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention I use those designer tools and had a look at the model. The model contains an attribute `Items`, but I cannot unfold it, so I guess there are no children?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54184/discussion-between-ermasca-and-user3153169).